# Why NASA world view (EOSDIS) have black strips?

Tags: imagery, satellite, nasa

There is the famous [NASA World View](https://earthdata.nasa.gov/labs/worldview/) site based on EOSDIS.

I relatively new to this and I wonder why & what are those black strips on the existing coverage? I also notice that the position of the strips is not the same on all days.

[image]

(This is different from the black part which is due to delay in processing time)

Comment: @AndreJ No it's not same... This is another my Q. There is 2 different issues: 1. Strips 2. Black part due to delay. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see the data that the satellites really gathered. On some places of the earth, no satellite has crossed during the day, hence you see nothing for that day.

It seems that the satellite swaths intersect in the North and South, but not around the equator.

If you switch between AQUA MODIS and TERRA MODIS, you see that the direction of the two swaths are different.

Comment: Wow - I expected such systems to cover 100% of the earth

Comment: For high resolution and less distortion, it might be better to limit the swath.

Comment: AndreJ  can you please have a look at my another Q regarding this images? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162692/why-nasa-world-view-eosdis-takes-time-to-get-world-wide-coverage-each-day