# NASA world view (EOSDIS) coverage delay per day - scanning footprint issue?

Tags: imagery, satellite, nasa

I noticed that in [NASA world view](https://earthdata.nasa.gov/labs/worldview/) web site it's take some time to get per day world wide coverage.
[image]

I made some calculations:

- The source is [Aqua](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMkok.png) & [Terra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terra_(satellite)) satellites
- Both have orbital period roughly 100 min
- [NASA](https://earthdata.nasa.gov/faq) SW image processing delay is 3h
- Capture possible only when it's day time on respective earth part

The only question is what is the scanning footprint? Usually it's almost "180 degrees". But maybe it's significant smaller due to requirements of high resolution imagery? Because if it's "regular" 180 degrees it should be faster.

Comment: Because the viewing platform is a finite number of satellites in orbit . . .

Comment: @mdsumner Can you explain? Still it's not clear for me. Thanks,

Comment: Search for details on satellite remote sensing coverage. The Earth is rotating, and it's large. High resolution imagery requires that you be relatively close and for a satellite to be close it must be moving (there's only one orbit distance that is "geo stationary", and that's not "close"). There's only so much a satellite can "see", and there's only so many we can launch. It takes time to orbit the Earth.

Comment: The [NASA FAQ](https://earthdata.nasa.gov/faq) states that the data is available within 3 hours of collection, and you're complaining that's not fast enough?

Comment: @Vince We know that satcom can be almost real time. So I expect every time some map tile is collected - it will be updated almost immediately, because the SW image processing shouldn't take 3 hours today.

Comment: You now have two questions. Please edit your question to have one question per Question.

Comment: You provided links to a wiki that says the platforms are in low earth orbit (LEO). The FAQ reports the viewfield to be +/-55 degrees, with a swath width of 2330km.

Comment: The orbital mechanics of satellites does not have a clear GIS component, is therefore off-topic for GIS SE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Together Terra and Aqua image the entire Earth every 1 to 2 days. The cross track swath is about 2330 km (about 3000 km is needed for "true" daily global coverage).

Compared to the geostationary satellites (35,786 km), sun synchronous satellites fly relatively low (600 to 850 km), their swath is thus smaller for a similar viewing angles.

The fact that sun synchronous satellites are moving relatively to the Earth surface is also a problem for the data transfer (data cannot be downloaded at any time). This has been improved, but "older" satellites had to be switched off because they didn't have enough bandwith to store all their images. Only recently do we have high resolution satellite with systematic acquisition (Landsat 8 and the Sentinels 1 & 2)

Note that a geostationary sensor only needs ~17.4 ° for an hemispherical coverage, so this is far from 180°.